# Vuetify data table show last page when loaded

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

How can I add prop "[page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-page)" so that the table shows the last page when loaded. The number of items is variable. Should I do `items.lenght/items-per-page` or is there any better way?

```
<v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="items"
                :search="search"
                multi-sort
                must-sort
                :sort-by="['date', 'number']"
                class="elevation-1"
                :items-per-page="10"
                :footer-props="{
                    showFirstLastPage:true,
                }"
                :loading="loading"
                height="540"
            ></v-data-table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: computed property `lastPage() {return Math.ceil(this.items.length/this.itemsPerPage);}`

Comment: And have you passed that as a `page` prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@grimdbx as per your above comments it is correct, you've taken the right try, you just need to set the page property with the computed result

The computed property always retruns the last page number on page load

```
computed: {
   lastPage() {return Math.ceil(this.items.length/10);}
}
```

> here instead of this.itemsPerPage you can replace with 10, since you
> have harcoded the items per page as per your above code

the final working code looks like

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      :page="lastPage"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
     lastPage() {return Math.ceil(this.desserts.length/5);}
  },
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Here is the working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/PoWeMgN?editors=1010